# Can't install PyAv on Mac, pkg-config is required

Tags: python, macos, pkg-config

I'm trying to install PyAv on my Mac. I'm using Pyzo, I run pip install av but I got this:

```
pkg-config is required for building PyAV; aborting!
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
pkg-config is required for building PyAV; aborting!

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/lk/fv_597y15lz7wqz2c4n3hb200000gn/T/pip-build-z1a_1u_k/av
```

I've tried to find it using Macports but Pyzo still can't find it, I also tried to install [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/macpkg/) but again, nothing. How can I solve this?

Comment: It looks like `pkg-config` isn't installed.  Since you're using Macports, do `sudo port install pkgconfig`.

Comment: I've done it, stil Python can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [brew](https://brew.sh):

```
brew install pkgconfig
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Deleted Formulae
cctools                                                       cctools-headers                                               ld64

==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/pkg-config-0.29.2.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring pkg-config-0.29.2.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.29.2: 11 files, 627.2KB
```